# What characters are word breakers in English for SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I can find what DLL supports English word breakers by using `sp_help_fulltext_system_components` but I have not been able to find an actual list of the word breaking characters for English (like blank, `.`, `%`, etc.).

Anyone know of a source for this info?

Comment: What does "nn3d14" mean. so the fulltext index will search for anything before and 3.14?
how do i interpret it? similarly in "nn1",what is it searching for

Answer (score 12):

This isn't an official list, but using a loop to work through a list of characters, and using `sys.dm_fts_parser` like so:

```
declare @i integer
declare @cnt integer
set @i=0
while @i<255
begin
  set @cnt=0
  select @cnt=COUNT(1) FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"word1'+REPLACE(CHAR(@i),'"','""')+'word2"', 1033, 0, 0)
  if @cnt>1
    begin
      print 'this char - '+CASE WHEN @i > 31 THEN char(@i) ELSE '' END+' - char('+convert(varchar(3),@i)+') is a word breaker'
    end
  set @i=@i+1
end
```

I can generate a list of characters that `sys.dm_fts_parser` reckons break the words. (`sys.dm_fts_parser` returns a row for every 'word' found in the import, so if it returns more than 1 row we had a word breaker)

This could be expanded to extended/non-english character sets by using `nchar()` rather than `char()` (and a bigger value for @i), and changing parameter 2 (lcid) in the call to `sys.dm_fts_parser`

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server (any version) considers any non alphanumeric character as a potential word breaker. Than means that there are situations where characters expected to break words are handled in a different way (direct or expanded) by the server.

A typical word breaker is the dot ('.')

These are some variations of dot handling (AICI).

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"The great .NET."', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "the", "great" and ".net"

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"The great ASP.NET."', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "the", "great", "asp.net", "asp" and "net"

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"G.I.S."', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "g.i.s." and "gis"

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"3.14"', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "3.14" and "nn3d14"

And it's not only the dot.

select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"data-driven apps"', 1033, 0, 0);

returns "data-driven", "data", "driven" and "apps"

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"1-0"', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "1-0", "1", "nn1", "0" and "nn0"

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"c# j# f# a#"', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "c#", "j#", "f" and "a" (f# is missing as a rule)

```
select display_term, * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"c c+ c++"', 1033, 0, 0);
```

returns "c", "c" and "c++"

The list of the (potential) word breakers (Stuart shows the way to get it in his answer) is the easy part. The difficult part is to get the list of the internal rules in use; they're handled/included in MSWB7*.dll, NaturalLanguage6.dll and NL7*.dll located at DRIVE:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\Binn